# Multiple nested queries to the same path?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have a nested structure like A -> B -> C
I'm trying to create a kind of query builder which would allow a query like

```
(A.a = 1 && A.B.b =2) || (A.B.b = 4 && A.B.C.c = 1)
```

or even more complex. So to do it I'm using multiple nested queries related with the same path

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "a": {
                    "value": "1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "B",
                  "query": {
                    "term": {
                      "B.b": {
                        "value": "2"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "B",
                  "query": {
                    "term": {
                      "B.b": {
                        "value": "4"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "B.C",
                  "query": {
                    "term": {
                      "B.C.c": {
                        "value": "1"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but the results are not what I would expect them to be. I know I can move the B.C.c condition to be an inner nested query but it's not the case. Maybe to simplify a bit I would expect a query like below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested"....
        },
        {
          "nested" to the same path as index 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

to be A && B but it seems it's not. For a query I'm struggling with it seems like the second nested condition is omitted.

The queries I need to build may have conditions from different levels grouped together, and every condition may be used multiple times in different groups. What is the correct approach for such a scenario?

**EDIT:**
It seems that both nested queries work on separate nested documents. Is there a way to make them run on the same nested document and preserve the query structure (two nested queries, not one)? So if the first nested query has condition A.a = 1 and the second nested is A.b = 2 the result would be 
A.a = 1 **&&** A.b = 2 insted of A.a = 1 **||** A.b = 2